# split a string by commas (,) SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, split

I would like to split a string by commas (,) or pipe (|) to each character in SQL SERVER. Example 'APPLE'. Expected result: 'A|P|P|L|E'. Preferably without creating function.

Comment: Use sql for retrieving and storing data to a database.  Use a real programming language for manipulating strings.

Comment: If you would like to use function there is already one created by @vzczc in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: isn't there a sqlServer function: RegexReplace ?  I'm not terribly familiar with sqlServer, however, in Oracle: select regexp_replace('APPLE','(.)','\1|') r  from dual works fine. It should be just a matter of using sqlServer's function instead ? If so, that should perform better than a function, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MikeNakis sometimes there is no "real language" front end to do this stuff with.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, I know. Then again, you can always throw your entire system away and rebuild it from scratch, adding a real language to it, or if that is not an option, quit your job and go work for a place which is not making you waste your time solving lame problems. My answer was meant to encourage him to stop for a moment and reconsider what he is doing with his life.

Comment: As Ditto said in Oracle I have used the regexp_replace. I need something simple as possible.

Comment: just curious....what is your end goal?

Comment: I wonder if there is any native function of SQL SERVER to separate each character of a string by commas or pipe.

Example: value of string 'ABCDE'.

I need something that returns 'A, B, C, D, E'. I do not want to create a new function, needs to be something native SQL SERVER.

In oracle I can deal with a native function (regexp_replace ('ABCDE', '\ 1 |' '().')

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CTE:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'APPLE'
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH cte(N, S) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS N, SUBSTRING(@s, 1, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1, SUBSTRING(@s, N + 1, 1)
    FROM cte
    WHERE N < LEN(@s)
) 
SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + '|', '') + S FROM cte
SELECT @result
```

Output:

```
A|P|P|L|E
```

Or even shorter version:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'APPLE'

;WITH cte(N, S, D) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS N, SUBSTRING(@s, 1, 1), D = SUBSTRING(@s, 1, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1, SUBSTRING(@s, N + 1, 1), D = D + '|' + SUBSTRING(@s, N + 1, 1)
    FROM cte
    WHERE N < LEN(@s)
) 
SELECT TOP 1 D FROM cte
ORDER BY N DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a concept like the "Tally Table String Splitter" to achieve what you want.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: a free email registration is worth deep knowledge IMO.

Comment: still a link to a possible solution is a comment, not an answer. Note a link may not be valid in 2 years when someone attempts to use it

Comment: I wonder if there is any native function of SQL SERVER to separate each character of a string by commas or pipe.

Example: value of string 'ABCDE'.

I need something that returns 'A, B, C, D, E'. I do not want to create a new function, needs to be something native SQL SERVER.

In oracle I can deal with a native function (regexp_replace ('ABCDE', '\ 1 |' '().')

Comment: @EdineiRaduvanski no, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(50) ='APPLE'

;WITH cte(x) as
(
  SELECT top (len(@txt)) ';' 
    + substring(@txt, row_number() over (order by (select 1)), 1)
  FROM master..spt_values x1
  cross join
  master..spt_values x2
  FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT stuff(x, 1, 1, '')
FROM CTE
```

Result

```
A;P;P;L;E
```

Comment: I wonder if there is any native function of SQL SERVER to separate each character of a string by commas or pipe.

Example: value of string 'ABCDE'.

I need something that returns 'A, B, C, D, E'. I do not want to create a new function, needs to be something native SQL SERVER.

In oracle I can deal with a native function (regexp_replace ('ABCDE', '\ 1 |' '().')

Comment: @EdineiRaduvanski no, there is not a native sql-server function for that.